# Jquery issue on css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I'm using a jQuery function to add a class on li tag when it is clicked. The problem is that the class is added for a moment and after disappear. Maybe , 'cause I'm working into joomla there are another jquery function or another php script thet modify li tag after my jquery function?

This is my website,http://debatoversigt.dk/ and if you click on left menu you can see background color appear for an instant and after disappear.

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery(".art-block li").click(function(){
jQuery(".selected").removeClass("selected");
jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
 });
```

and css:

```
.selected{

background-color:red!important;

}
```

Comment: Well, it's because the page refresh happens.

Comment: I've suspected it. How can resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click it?

Comment: I would that background color stay on li clicked, and disappear only when you click on other item in menu

Comment: I know that, I meant do you want a page refresh or to use AJAX to update the page content?

Comment: Under li this is an a href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is removed because the page refreshes. You will need to put code into your page that looks at the current page's URL and applies your `selected` CSS style to the appropriate menu item. Doing this will still let it function as a menu item but also remain selected on a page load.

One method to consider is to leave the code you have in place already and add this to the page:

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      var windowloc = window.location.pathname;
      jQuery(".art-block li").each(function() {
           if(jQuery(this).attr("href")==windowloc) {
                jquery(this).addClass("selected");
           }
      });
 });
```

Another method to use (which is more work but also more robust) is to add a class to the `body` tag of the page so that it corresponds with a menu item. That would actually be a cleaner method as you can then highlight menu items for child pages and not just for the top level sections. You would need to incorporate a unique CSS class with each list item so that you can compare them on page load. I found a [tutorial on adding body classes to Joomla](http://crosstown.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/joomla/adding-css-class-to-joomla-pages) that may be helpful for this approach.

You would use something like this JavaScript code to highlight the menu item once you had your CSS classes in place (both on the menu `li` items and the body class):

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
           var bodyclass = jQuery("body").attr("class");
           jQuery(".art-block li").each(function() {
                if(jQuery(this).hasClass(bodyclass)) {
                     jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
                }
           });
      });
 });
```

Either of these methods would work on your current website, but pick what you feel makes the most sense for your website now and going forward.

Comment: I've tried your first solution but doesn't work, I've insert a console.log(jQuery(this).attr("baseURI")) in each statement and is ever undefined

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to keep that page refresh, but have the proper menu item highlighted, you need to figure out a way to select the proper menu item. For example, you can compare the current url with each menu items' href attribute, and if they match highlight that item.

The other option is to use AJAX to update the content of the page. From your comments, I assume that's not what you want, but anyway, to do that, you need to prevent the default anchor behavior and load the content. That way you won't have to worry about the disappearing highlight and your code will work perfectly (but you'll run into other issues typical for one-page AJAX websites like URL states, browser history buttons, etc...).